# Category Implementation in a database

Tags: sql, mongodb, database-design, nosql

I'm building a system that involves users and teachers. In this particular system however I would like to categorize the teachers, but the tricky part is the categories are dynamic thus they can change anytime.

I have to have some functions, since I'm developing the backend;

- The first one is **showAllCategories()**, that shows all the **main** categories.
- Second is the **showSubcategories()** which shows the subcategories of a category()
- Third is the **showContent()**, which in this case shows the teacher's information.

Before asking mighty Stack-Overflowers how would this be efficiently implemented, I thought I could use a doubly linked list approach where in categories table **CategoryName**, **Before**, **After**, **Content** and if the category did not have the after, the content would be pointing to the teacher's table. This is my classic SQL approach however I'm using **MongoDB** and since I'm a beginner I wonder if I could take the advantage of NoSQL in this particular situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDb natively supports the Array type, which behaves actually more like a list. With [`$push`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24push) and [`$pull`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24pull) you can add and remove elements from such an array field. [`$addToSet`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24addToSetand%24each) even makes sure there are no dublicates.

Now is the question of how the categories are stored. You can make a collection `categories` with the main categories, and they would be having a field each that has the array of the sub-categories:

```
{"_id": "science", "sub": ["chemist", "physicist", "biology"]}
{"_id": "languages", "sub": ["english", "german", "spanish"]}
```

Your `teacher` collection on the other hand would then have an array of embedded documents, the categories of the teacher. They are duplicates of those found in the `categories` collection, minus the fields that you won't need in the teacher view. This way you avoid joins, since they don't exist in MongoDB.

```
{
 "_id": ObjectId(...),
 "name": {"first": "Foo", "last": "Bar"},
 "categories": ["chemist", "biology"]
}
```

The rest I am sure you can think up.

**Addition:** In short, use the flexible types that MongoDB offers, and don't worry about data redundancy. Embed documents often and don't forget the indexes.

Comment: Thanks for the great approach. However I do have one question. Since you've mentioned that I would store the main categories with the list that represents the sub categories. Assume we have the case where the main categeory id 1 with sub categories [2,3,4]. Category 3 is a obviously a subcategory so where should I store the sub categories of 3 as it can have more than one, without being a main category

Comment: Oh, I didn't know you can have sub-sub-categories. But that is not a problem at all, since MongoDB is dynamic. That means you can store the sub-sub-categories in the list as well: `[{id: cat1}, {id: cat2, subs: [...]}, {id: cat3}]`. If there is a `subs` field, the app would know there are sub categories. Thus you can build a hierarchical tree.